# C++ alternative to pre-processor #ifdef / #endif

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a StopWatch class which I use to measure execution time.  I instantiate several different stopwatches to log execution time by category.  For example:

```
#ifdef EXEC_TIME_PROF
StopWatch func1sw;
StopWatch func2sw;
#endif

void foo() {
#ifdef EXEC_TIME_PROF
func1sw.start();
#endif

func1();

#ifdef EXEC_TIME_PROF
func1sw.stop();
func2sw.start();
#endif

func2();

#ifdef EXEC_TIME_PROF
func2sw.stop();
#endif
}

#ifdef EXEC_TIME_PROF
func1sw.logTime();
func2sw.logTime();
#endif
```

So the actual 2-line function becomes a lot longer and more cluttered with all the #ifdef statements.  The reason that I use the #ifdef is because I don't want the statements to be compiled in a non-profiling / production build.  Does anyone know a better way of doing this?  My development environment is Windows / Visual Studio C++ 2015.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the macro to switch between a class that does something and a class that does nothing at all.  The compiler should recognize that and exclude it from compilation.

```
#ifdef EXEC_TIME_PROF

// your actual implementation
class StopWatch
{
    // ...
};

#else

// completely empty implementation
class StopWatch
{
public:
    void start() {}
    void stop() {}
    void logTime() {}
};

#endif
```

If you still want to use `StopWatch` for other things in production, then just use something else like `ProfilingStopWatch` roughly as follows:

```
#ifdef EXEC_TIME_PROF

typedef StopWatch ProfilingStopWatch;

#else

// completely empty implementation
class ProfilingStopWatch
{
public:
    void start() {}
    void stop() {}
    void logTime() {}
};

#endif
```

So, in case it's not completely clear, you can remove the other macro tests from your code and use the class normally:

```
ProfilingStopWatch func1sw;
ProfilingStopWatch func2sw;

void foo()
{
    func1sw.start();
    func1();
    func1sw.stop();

    func2sw.start();
    func2();
    func2sw.stop();
}

func1sw.logTime();
func2sw.logTime();
```

Comment: Thanks paddy, I like that solution. Will the compiler (Visual Studio 2015 C++ in this case) really recognize the empty class and ignore it (assuming that it's built with production optimization switches turned on)?

Comment: Yes, it should not be included.  The class stores no data, and its member functions are declared inline and do nothing.  So, wherever the class is used, nothing is added to the stack, and wherever the members are called, nothing happens.  This is bread and butter for compilers, and even trashy ones like VS 2015 can handle it. ;)  If you are highly concerned about this, I suggest making a very simple test program and look at its disassembly.

Comment: Note that you could make further improvements by using some kind of helper class that manages the timer start/stop via RAII idiom.  Or there's probably an elaborate way to use modern C++ language features to do this AND invoke the functions with proper argument forwarding, etc.  Similar to Remy's answer that uses macros, but more flexible and C++-like.  But I felt this is beyond the scope of what you're asking for.  Could be a fun exercise, if you wanna deep-dive.

Comment: Thanks @paddy, I thought about extending this a bit to take advantage of the RAII idiom so that only one stopwatch needs to be declared at the start of the function.  Initialize the start clock in the constructor, then log the time in the destructor. Something like that should work. I also created a stopwatch manager that keeps track of the last stopwatch started and automatically stops and logs / accumulates the time when the next stopwatch is started.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add some extra macros to wrap the stopwatches, eg:

```cpp
#define concat(a,b) a ## b

#ifdef EXEC_TIME_PROF
StopWatch func1sw;
StopWatch func2sw;

#define RUN_FUNC(funcName) \
    concat(funcName,sw).start(); \
    funcName(); \
    concat(funcName,sw).stop();

#else

#define RUN_FUNC(funcName) \
    funcName();

#endif

void foo() {
     RUN_FUNC(func1);
     RUN_FUNC(func2);
}

#ifdef EXEC_TIME_PROF
func1sw.logTime();
func2sw.logTime();
#endif
```